# Can't get Jquery success method to work

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

For the life of me cannot figure out how to display the values I'm returning from my 'cics' object from my controller.  When I debug the controller it is returning the value.  But I can't seem to figure out my 'Success' method on the ajax call.  Can anyone please help me with where I'm going wrong?  Also, This can have multiple products so I'm trying to keep it specific to that element.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 function FillProductbyupc(el) {
        var val = el.value;
        var container = $(el).parent().parent();
        var pcics = container.children(".cics");
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('product');


        $.ajax({
            url: '/Case/GetData/',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: "upc=" + val,
            success: function (cics) {
                //container.cics.val(cics.CorpItemCode);

                $("#upc").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $("#corpitemcode").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $("#itemdesc").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $("#corpitemcode").append(
                    $('#corpitemcode').val(cics.CorpItemCode));

                $("#itemdesc").append(
                    $('#itemdesc').val(cics.ItemDsc));

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("UPC does not exist");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my product.

```
<div class="product">
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UPC)<small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk text-danger"></span></small>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UPC, null, new { @class = "form-control produpc", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.UPC), @onblur = "FillProductbyupc(this)" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UPC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PLU)<small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk text-danger"></span></small>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PLU, null, new { @class = "form-control prodplu", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.PLU) })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PLU, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>CIC</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.CIC, new { @class = "form-control prodcic" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>Desc</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Description, new { @class = "form-control proddesc" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>Size</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Size, new { @class = "form-control prodsize" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>Shelf Price</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.ShelfPrice, new { @class = "form-control prodprice" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>Like CIC</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.LikeCIC, new { @class = "form-control prodlikecic" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.RemoveLink("Remove", "div.product", "input.mark-for-delete")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller.

```
  public JsonResult GetData(string upc, decimal? corpitemcode)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(upc))
        {
            upc = upc.Replace("-", "");
        }

        CICS cics = new CICS();
        cics = CICSManager.GetbyUPCorCorp(upc, corpitemcode);

        return Json(cics, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Working function

```
function FillProductbyupc(el) {
var val = el.value;
var container = $(el).parent().parent();
var pcics = $(container).find('.prodcic');
var pdesc = $(container).find('.itemdsc');

$.ajax({
    url: '/Case/GetData/',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: "upc=" + val,
    success: function (cics) {
        pcics.val(cics.CorpItemCode);
        pdesc.val(cics.ItemDsc);


    },

    error: function () {
        alert("UPC does not exist");
    }
});
```

}

Comment: What do you expect `$("#corpitemcode").append(
                    $('#corpitemcode').val(cics.CorpItemCode));` to do? You're appending an element to itself.

Comment: And `.val(cics.CorpItemCode)` is only meaningful for input elements. What type of element is `#corpitemcode`?

Comment: All of those are input elements.  I'm trying to fill those other textboxes with what is pulled back from the 'cics' object.  I just can't figure out how to populate those.

Comment: If they're input elements, why are you calling `$("#corpitemcode").html("")`? That's only meaningful for HTML nodes.

Comment: Yeah... My code may be a little off.  I've just tried everything and I don't know how to make those populate.

Comment: Did you see my answer? It would help if you posted the real HTML instead of that framework code.

Comment: I added the way in the original post that I got it to work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html()` and `.append()` are for adding to HTML nodes. I suspect what you want is:

```
        success: function (cics) {
            //container.cics.val(cics.CorpItemCode);

            $("#upc").val("");
            $("#corpitemcode").val(cics.CorpItemCode);
            $("#itemdesc").val(cics.ItemDsc);
        },
```

There's no need to clear before inserting new HTML.